# Jenkins pipeline update global environment variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I currently have a Jenkins pipeline job that runs a groovy Jenkinsfile to run a go script and returns either an empty string or an error string in which case an email is sent. I want to set this return value to a Global Variable such that the next build that starts can check the previous jobs' return value and determine if it needs to send out another email (or suppress if its the same error)

I'm open to any suggestions (EnvInject Plugin is vulnerable hence I haven't considered using it currently)

Comment: How about triggering the other job based on the first jobs result using the "Build Other Projects" functionality? https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/how-to-use-jenkins-for-job-chaining-and-visualizations/

Comment: The current job is a cron job which runs every 2 minutes relies on another system (Which the go script essentially polls their endpoint and errors when it's unavailable)

Comment: Also worth noting, each jenkins builds run on different nodes so the method of creating a file to store the old results will not work